# Add minutes to time object

Tags: javascript, timepicker

I have three input fields and this javascript:

```js
    function deductMinutes(time, minsToDeduct) {
        function D(J){ return (J<10? '0':'') + J};
        var inputTime = document.getElementById("time").value;
        var deductMins = ('75');
        var piece = time.split(':');
        var mins = piece[0]*60 + +piece[1] + -minsToDeduct;
        return D(mins%(24*60)/60 | 0) + ':' + D(mins%60); 
        }  
    document.getElementById('start_time').value=(deductMinutes('18:30', '75'));  // '17:15'

    function addMinutes(time, minsToAdd) {
        function D(J){ return (J<10? '0':'') + J};
        var inputTime = document.getElementById("time").value;
        var addMins = ('20');
        var piece = time.split(':');
        var mins = piece[0]*60 + +piece[1] + +minsToAdd;
        return D(mins%(24*60)/60 | 0) + ':' + D(mins%60); 
        }  
    document.getElementById('end_time').value=(addMinutes('18:30', '20'));  // '18:50'
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>JavaScript setMinutes Method</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   
<p><label>Select time: </label><input type="text" id="time" name="time" onChange="addMinutes(this.value)"  /></p>

<p><label>Start time: <input type="text" id="start_time" name="start_time" readonly="readonly" /> less 75 minutes</label></p>
<p><label>End time: <input type="text" id="end_time" name="end_time" readonly="readonly" /> plus 20 minutes</label></p>

   </body>
</html>
```

I need 75 minutes to be deducted from the time value entered in the first input ("time") from a timepicker, and entered into the second field ("start_time"), then 20 minutes added to the time value and entered into the third field ("end_time"). Currently it works with a predifined time in the calculation being 18:30 in the last line, but I need this to be replaced with whatever the user selects into the 'time' field input.

Aaaaarrrgghh! I have gotten so far with this darn thing, but can't get past this last bit!

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What have you tried, and what actual problem did you run into?

Comment: This seems like an odd approach, the built in Date object has ways to add/remove minutes already, working with your date as a string is making a lot of extra work for yourself.

Comment: So a user selects a date and time for vehicle pickup on a page prepopulated with journey information such as journey time in minutes. When they enter their chosen time via the datepicker, using the 'onChange' function, I want this script to populate two extra fields as above, so that I have an accurate start time and end time for driver, which will be submitted with form. I just need this script to use the user time instead of the prewritten '18:30'

Comment: I have posted this question in a different way here if that helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66229145/add-deduct-minutes-from-user-time-input